# GraphFrames shortestPaths fine in local mode, but an error when done on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I am learning Apache Spark and graphframes trying to get shortestPaths to work on my 6 node cluster using the code provided here https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html

```
    import org.graphframes.examples
    val g: GraphFrame = examples.Graphs.friends  // get example graph

    val results = g.shortestPaths.landmarks(Seq("a", "d")).run()
    results.select("id", "distances").show()
```

When ran locally the shortestPaths works, however when ran using the cluster I receive the following warning followed by an error:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 40, 192.168.0.51, executor 4):
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2127)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2022)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2016)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
 at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
 at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my spark submit I have been using:

```
 ~/spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-submit --class "PSKQ" --master spark://192.168.0.42:7077 target/scala-2.11/pskq_2.11-1.0.jar
```

My SBT file

```
 name := "PSKQ"

 version := "1.0"

 scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

 resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.1.0",
  "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"
 )
```